# Why is my ActionButton base-class being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, inheritance

My "base class" does not seem to be populating correctly.  Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var exceptions = {
        NotImplementedException: function (message) {
            this.name = 'NotImplementedException';
            this.message = message || 'Property or method is not implemented.';
        }
    };
    exceptions.NotImplementedException.prototype = Error.prototype;

    function ActionButton() {
        this.execute = function () {
            throw new exceptions.NotImplementedException("Execute is not implemented.");
        };
        this.render = function (data) {
            throw new exceptions.NotImplementedException("Render is not implemented.");
        };
        this.$template = function () {
            throw new exceptions.NotImplementedException("$template is not implemented.");
        };
    };

    function ImageActionButton() {
        this.image = { url: '' };
    };
    function TextActionButton() {
        this.text = '';
    };
    function StandardActionButton() {
        this.text = '';
        this.image = { url: '' };
    };
    function MenuActionButton() {
        this.buttons = [];
    };

    ImageActionButton.prototype = new ActionButton();
    ImageActionButton.prototype.constructor = ImageActionButton;

    TextActionButton.prototype = new ActionButton();
    TextActionButton.prototype.constructor = TextActionButton;

    StandardActionButton.prototype = new ActionButton();
    StandardActionButton.prototype.constructor = StandardActionButton;

    MenuActionButton.prototype = new ActionButton();
    MenuActionButton.prototype.constructor = MenuActionButton;

    // This fails
    if (ImageActionButton.prototype != ActionButton) {
        alert("ImageActionButton prototype is not ActionButton!");
    }
    // This works
    if (ImageActionButton.prototype.constructor != ImageActionButton) {
        alert("ImageActionButton prototype.constructor is not ImageActionButton!");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) instead of comparing like you are.

```
if (ImageActionButton instanceof ActionButton) {
    alert("ImageActionButton prototype is not ActionButton!");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't working.  I believe it is because ActionButton cannot be found in the prototypal chain...which is why I am perplexed.  Thanks!